# PHP JSON array with a dot in the key name

Tags: php, json

I have the JSON below that is a response from an API. The key names have dots in their names, and the coding I use will not recognize it.

JSON:

```
{

    "unit.count": 40413,
    "device.count": 4893,
    "registration.count": 3951
}
```

the code I am using to read this is below.

CODE:

```
$myArray = json_decode($response,true);

echo $myArray['unit.count'];
```

There is no value echo'd

Any help would be appreciated.

Robert

Since posting, I have found the problem in the API sending the JSON script.

Thanks to everyone that answered.

Comment: From what I see, everything works as expected. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: It is not displaying anything for me on my side. Just a blank page

Comment: you can try with bellow answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. Verify that you have **valid json** and you are using **correct variable**:

```
$json = '{

    "unit.count": 40413,
    "device.count": 4893,
    "registration.count": 3951
}';

$myArray = json_decode($json,true);

echo $myArray['unit.count']; //op: 40413
```

See an example here:https://eval.in/817059

Answer (score 1):

> try this one

```
//convert  json format to array is important just pass second parameter as true  
  $arr = array( 
                  "unit.count" => 40413,
                  "device.count" => 4893,
                  "registration.count"=>3951
  );

  $response= json_encode($arr);
  $myArray = json_decode($response,true); 

  echo $myArray['unit.count']; //40413
```

Comment: Second parameter is already true check see in question `$myArray = json_decode($response,true);`

Answer (score 1):

please try this below code.

```
<?php 
  $response = '{

"unit.count": 40413,
"device.count": 4893,
"registration.count": 3951
}';

$myArray = json_decode($response,true);

echo $myArray['unit.count'];

?>
```